# .NET nHibernate: resource file not found

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I can't seem to manage to get my nHibernate test project running, I'm using the following config files and code:

country.hbm.xml marked as embedded resource:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="SVL.Models.CountryModel, SVL" table="country">
  <id name="Id" type="int" />
  <property name="Name" type="String" length="200" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My nhibernate config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<session-factory>
<!-- properties -->
<property name="connection.provider">
  NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">
  NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">
  Server=localhost;Database=svl;User ID=root;Password=pfje1008;
</property>
<property name="dialect">
  NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect
</property>

<mapping resource="country.hbm.xml" assembly="SVL" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>`
```

And finally the code that sets up the config of hibernate:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
 cfg.Configure();

 var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

 var thisAssembly = typeof(T).Assembly;
 cfg.AddAssembly(thisAssembly);
```

For some reason it keeps telling me the resource file cannot be found...

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: [MappingException: Resource not found: country.hbm.xml]
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception) +131
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly) +208
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.DoConfigure(ISessionFactoryConfiguration factoryConfiguration) +936
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlReader textReader) +327
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(String fileName, Boolean ignoreSessionFactoryConfig) +166

Comment: If I hard code the mapping config file in my configuration, then it does work btw: `cfg.AddFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("country.hbm.xml"));`

Comment: it appears you should add the assembly name to the mapping..

when using ´<mapping resource="SVL.country.hbm.xml" assembly="SVL" />´ it does work, sigh ..

Answer (score 2):

Try getting rid of the `<mapping resource="country.hbm.xml" assembly="SVL" />` line, I don't remember ever doing that when using embedded resources.

Comment: when I do that, I'm not getting an error, but also not getting any return values.

if I do add the config like in ´ cfg.AddFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("country.hbm.xml"));´ I get my 3 records that are currently in the database..

Comment: if you don't add the mapping file, then how do you make your mappings?

Comment: I haven't used NHibernate for a while admittedly, although when I did I used embedded resources and I'm sure I didn't list them all individually, I just added the assembly they were embedded in: `cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Customer).Assembly);`

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues, firstly the .Configure method you're calling is looking for a file with the connection string, dialect and other settings in it (or possibly checking your web.config for these), and secondly you're building the session factory BEFORE you add your assembly to the configuration.

You need to add your assembly to the configuration before building the session factory because the process of building the session factory is based off the current state of the configuration.

So something like:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
var thisAssembly = typeof(T).Assembly;
cfg.AddAssembly(thisAssembly); 
cfg.Configure();

var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

To fix the exception you're getting, I would suggest any of:

1. rename your NHibernate config file to hibernate.cfg.xml (which is what it looks for by default if it can't find it in the app/web.config)
2. put the configuration in your app/web.config (see http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/07/17/nhibernate-configuration.aspx)
3. specify the name of your NHibernate config file in the call to Configure - ie. cfg.Configure("my-nhibernate-config.config")